# fullCalendar event don't show on week

Tags: fullcalendar

Sorry for my English, I'm french

```
var options = {
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title,today',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
        prev: '<i class="icon-chevron-left cal_prev" />',
        next: '<i class="icon-chevron-right cal_next" />',
        today: "aujourd'hui",
        month: "mois",
        day:"jour",
        week: "semaine"
    },
    monthNames:['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort:['janv.','févr.','mars','avr.','mai','juin','juil.','août','sept.','oct.','nov.','déc.'],
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: [ 'Dim','Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
    events: 'actions.php?IDuser=1',
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar(options);
```

My json:

```
[{"id":"2","title":"rt","start":"1367236500","end":"1367236500","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"5","title":"fgh","start":"1367236800","end":"1367596800","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"3","title":"test\u00e9 par moi","start":"1367237100","end":"1367258700","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"4","title":"dfsgfdgd","start":"1367323200","end":"1367326800","url":null,"allDay":"false"}]
```

I see events on all-days view but nothing on hours in week or day view.

I added `allDayDefault: false` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the json feed the `allDay = false` must be boolean. You have to remove the quotes from the "false"

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people who are blocked on this later.
It's an optional parameter but the event won't show in week or day view if it's not specified  in your json object return by your script! It will be displayed only in month view.

This is an error of the plugin documentation so be careful !

Answer (score 0):

Remember and cross check about these values in your jQuery `minTime:` and `maxTime:` values, because FullCalendar works in 24 hours time format and remembers the time you are rendering it is according to the FullCalendar format.